# Please How to draw multigraphs in python? I tried it do so using networkx libraries but only one connection between two nodes is drawn

Tags: python, graph-theory

Please How to draw multigraphs in python? 
I tried it do so using networkx libraries but only one connection between two nodes is drawn

Comment: Can you put the code you tried so far in your question?

Comment: import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
#import graphviz
import pydot
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import write_dot
#from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import write_dot
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import write_dot

G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_node('A')
G.add_node('B')
G.add_edge('A','B', label='foo')
G.add_edge('A','B', label='bar')

nx.write_dot(G,'multi.dot')

Comment: and here 's the error msg i get : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'write_dot'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do something like this, it should allow you to draw multiple edges between the same nodes.  However, when drawn they will overlap because they are drawn as straight lines.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graph = nx.MultiGraph() # Must use MultiGraph rather than Graph

graph.add_nodes_from(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
print('There are {} nodes in the graph: {}'.format(graph.number_of_nodes(), 
graph.nodes()))

graph.add_edges_from([('A', 'C'), 
                      ('A', 'B'), 
                      ('A', 'E'),
                      ('B', 'E'),
                      ('B', 'D'),
                      ('C', 'A')])
print('There are {} edges in the graph: {}'.format(graph.number_of_edges(), 
graph.edges()))

nx.draw(graph, with_labels = True, font_weight='bold')
plt.show()

# Confirms two edges between A and C
print(graph.number_of_edges('A', 'C'))
```

This will allow you to store attributes on multiple edges between nodes.  I've not seen any pure networkx options that will allow you to visualize these lines separately.

You can do this using GraphViz:

Here are the docs: https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

You can pip install using:

```
pip install graphviz
```

And then you have to install the executable.  I used homebrew on Mac so I simply typed:

```
brew install graphviz
```

Here is a basic example of two nodes that point to each other:

```
from graphviz import Digraph

g = Digraph()

nodes = ['A', 'B', 'C']
edges = [['A', 'B'],['B', 'C'],['B', 'A']]

for node in nodes:
    g.node(node)

for edge in edges:
    start_node = edge[0]
    end_node = edge[1]
    g.edge(start_node, end_node)

g.view()
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you alot for your help , i did exactly what you have said , but iget this error messsage when i try to run the second code(using graphviz) :  
ImportError: cannot import name 'Digraph'

Comment: it would be really helpful if you can use code examples manipulating Multigraphs (not digraphs) on  which i am working , thank you again for your help.

Comment: i would like to inform you that i have added graphviz to my system PATH and it worked , THANK YOU ALOT ,I APPRECIATE YOUR HELP

Comment: Happy I could help!  Feel free up upvote or accept the answer if you think it will help others!